# How to resolve from other modules in Swinject

Tags: ios, swift, swinject, tuist

Modularized the project using Tuist. I made RepositoryAssembly and UseCaseAssembly on the Data module and Domain module. Assembler is located in InjectManager and runs in AppDelegate in the App module.

```swift
// InjectManager.swift
public struct InjectManager {
    public static func inject(container: Container) -> Assembler {
        return Assembler([
            RepositoryAssembly(),
            UseCaseAssembly()
        ], container: container)
    }
}
```

```swift
 ...
private var assembler: Assembler!
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        assembler = InjectManager.inject(container: InjectContainer.container)
        return true
    }
 ...
```

Also, when performing InjetcContainer.container.resolve in MainFeature module, the following error is displayed.

```swift
Swinject: Resolution failed. Expected registration:
    { Service: FetchRankingListUseCase, Factory: Resolver -> FetchRankingListUseCase }
Available registrations:
MainFeature/MainInteractor.swift:41: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2022-04-26 23:36:21.127977+0900 GRIG[5952:4943332] MainFeature/MainInteractor.swift:41: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

When I print the InjectContainer.container,

```swift
[
    { Service: FetchRankingListUseCase, Factory: Resolver -> FetchRankingListUseCase, ObjectScope: graph },
    { Service: GRIGRepository, Factory: Resolver -> GRIGRepository, ObjectScope: graph }
]
```

Why is this error coming out? Could you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: you only register an `Assembler`
 ?

Comment: ```swift
public struct UseCaseAssembly: Assembly {
    public func assemble(container: Container) {
        container.register(FetchRankingListUseCase.self) { r in
            FetchRankingListUseCase(grigRepository: r.resolve(GRIGRepository.self)!)
        }
    }
    public init() {}
}
```

```swift
public struct RepositoryAssembly: Assembly {
    public func assemble(container: Container) {
        container.register(GRIGRepository.self) { _ in
            GRIGRepositoryImpl()
        }
    }
    public init() {}
}
```
Are you talking about this?

Comment: yes thank you, so this is called on the init of your Assembler ? with the same container ?
Are you sure that you try to resolve your object from the correct Container ?

Comment: When I prin(InjectContainer.container) before resolve
```swift
[
    { Service: FetchRankingListUseCase, Factory: Resolver -> FetchRankingListUseCase, ObjectScope: graph },
    { Service: GRIGRepository, Factory: Resolver -> GRIGRepository, ObjectScope: graph }
]
``` 
It became a register in the container. I did it in InjectContainer.container when I resolve. So the container is correct

Comment: how do you define `InjectContainer.container` ?

Comment: ```swift
import Swinject

public struct InjectContainer {
    public static let container = Container()
}
``` 
in 'ThirdPartyLib' module's 'InjectContainer.swift' file